# Passing XLSX sheet to csvDictReader

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

Is there a way that I can pass an Excel sheet to `csv DictReader` without needing to create a new csv file from the sheet?

I want to be able to access the data contained in the Excel sheet with the same way that one can access data with `csv DictReader`

Comment: I would recommend `pandas.read_excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @Clade's suggestion I used `pandas.read_excel`

```
import csv
import easygui as eg
import pandas as pd

sheets = ['UC Apps', 'IOS Devices']

for sheet in sheets:
    xlsx_data = pd.read_excel(eg.fileopenbox(), sheet, index_col=None)
    csv_as_string = xlsx_data.to_csv(index=False)
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_as_string.splitlines())

    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```